# On centos 7 and logging with php 7 syslog function tabs are logged as ascii hex code \x09

Tags: php

Does anyone know why when I run the code below on a centos 7.5 machine the tabs are outputted as \x09? I've done a lot of digging and can not find a solution. I believe this may be related my locale settings but everything is set to en_US.UTF-8.

`php -r 'syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "test\t");'`

this produces:

`Apr  3 08:06:23 php: test\x09`

On my laptop which is running ubuntu 18.04 the tab is logged as I expect, with 8 spaces.

Note I have tested this using syslog, syslog-ng and rsyslog all produce the same result.

Using strace it looks like php is escaping the tab

`sendto(3, "<13>Apr  3 09:27:35 php: test\\x0"..., 38, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 38`

Comment: For `rsyslog` - have you checked that `$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive` in `rsyslog.conf` is **Off** ?

Comment: I've done that and it still logging \x09. It did allow it work if I ran ```printf "hello\tthere" | logger```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apparently in php 7 they added a syslog.filter setting and it defaults to no_ctrl. I changed it to 'all' and php stopped escaping the tab.

```
; Set this to disable filtering control characters (the default).
; Some loggers only accept NVT-ASCII, others accept anything that's not
; control characters. If your logger accepts everything, then no filtering
; is needed at all.
; Allowed values are:
;   ascii (only base ASCII characters)
;   no_ctrl (all characters except control characters)
;   all (all characters)
syslog.filter = all
```